# Get background color in color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to design a color picker with fixed values. As I'm a newbie to web programming I'm not sure how to proceed. The task is to get background color on selecting a palette's background and with that color, another div element's background has to change.

In this HTML `#palette` has 30 colors, `color-1` to `color-30`. On selecting the color from the palette the background of `.color-container` has to change. Thanks in advance.

```html
<div id="palette">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colors" id="color-1"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-2"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-3"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-4"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-5"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colors" id="color-7"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-8"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-9"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-10"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-11"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-12"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colors" id="color-13"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-14"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-15"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-16"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-17"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-18"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colors" id="color-19"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-20"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-21"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-22"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-23"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-24"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colors" id="color-25"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-26"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-27"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-28"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-29"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-30"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="color-container">
  <h1 style="color: black" id="container-text">Text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: So sounds like you need to add event listeners.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to detect which div was clicked, all yours div elements has same colors class so that must be your selector, after that you need to extract the click div id. You can get it doing this:

```
$('.colors').on('click', function () {
    var colorid = this.id;    
});
```

After that you can play with colorid value, I don't know how you going to specify which color is id color-1, color-2, etc. So just as an example I use a switch so your code is the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.colors').on('click', function () {
    var colorid = this.id;
    
      switch(colorid) {
        case "color-1":
           $('.color-container h1').css("color", "red");
        break;
        case "color-2":
          $('.color-container h1').css("color", "blue");
        break;
        case "color-3":
          $('.color-container h1').css("color", "yellow");
        break;
        case "color-4":
          $('.color-container h1').css("color", "orange");
        break;
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="palette">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colors" id="color-1">1</div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-2">2</div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-3">3</div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-4">4</div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-5"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colors" id="color-7"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-8"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-9"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-10"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-11"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-12"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colors" id="color-13"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-14"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-15"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-16"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-17"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-18"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colors" id="color-19"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-20"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-21"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-22"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-23"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-24"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colors" id="color-25"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-26"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-27"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-28"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-29"></div>
    <div class="colors" id="color-30"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="color-container">
  <h1 style="color: black" id="container-text">Text</h1>
</div>
```

This should solve your problem.